# Invalid certificate error on helm release after failed helm release

Tags: kubernetes-helm, cert-manager

Helm release can fail, so I am using `--atomic` flag in helm upgrade command to achieve zero downtime. But for this scenario, I am getting certificate invalid error from cert-manager,

Error,

```
* Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": failed to call webhook: Post "https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=10s": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Scenario:

1. Cert-Manager Helm release passed
2. Custom Service Helm release failed in the very first attempt
3. Custom Service Helm release 2nd attempt fails with the error mentioned above

But this works,

1. Cert-Manager Helm release passed
2. Custom Service Helm release failed in the very first attempt
3. Uninstall Cert-Manager if 2
4. Install Cert-Manager again
5. Do Custom Service Helm release (this can again pass/fail but not because of certificate error)

I dont want to install cert-manager for every failure case, is there any other way?

Comment: cert-manager version: 1.11.2, helm version: v3.13.3